# Compute the average and grade of the students

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

In this task I should write a JavaScript program which computes the average marks of the listed students:
David   80, Vinoth  77, Divya   88, Ishitha     95 , Thomas     68.

The expected approach is to create an array using the data given, loop thru it using a for loop. its important to use the for loop as that's what I'm currently studying, and would like to understand why its not working. (I don't know yet how to use the forEach method)

The problem happens when I run the loop and it returns NaN. I dont know why it happens, or what Im doing wrong here.

```
const nameGrade = [["David", 80], ["Vinoth", 77], ["Divya", 88], ["Ishitha", 95], ["Thomas", 68]];

let sumGrades;
    console.log(`Value of sumGrades right after definition: ${sumGrades}`); //this returns undefined which is expected
    
    for (let i = 0; i < nameGrade.length; i++){
        sumGrades += nameGrade[i][1];
        console.log(`Value of sumGrades after the for loop: ${sumGrades}`); //this returns NaN, and I dont know why!!
    }

    let avg = (sumGrades/nameGrade.length);
    console.log(`Value of sumGrades/array.length: ${avg}`);
```

Comment: You are getting `NaN` because the initial value of `sumGrades` is `undefined`. `undefined + <number> = NaN`. Initialize it with `0`.

Comment: @user120242 - Now **that's** an accurate dupetarget! :-)

Comment: Hi, You should organize your data with an object which will make them more understandable, like : `[{"name":"David","grade": 80}, {"name":"Vinoth","grade": 77}]`. You can then access to the properties like that : `nameGrade[i].name` or `nameGrade[i].grade`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder it was actually not easy to find :\

Comment: @FelixKling yes! Thank you! And you helped me understand why undefined+number = NaN

@user120242yes! Its the same problem. I was not able to find that question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

initialize as 0 `let sumGrades=0;`

```js
const nameGrade = [["David", 80], ["Vinoth", 77], ["Divya", 88], ["Ishitha", 95], ["Thomas", 68]];

let sumGrades=0;
    console.log(`Value of sumGrades right after definition: ${sumGrades}`); //this returns undefined which is expected
    
    for (let i = 0; i < nameGrade.length; i++){
        sumGrades += nameGrade[i][1];
        console.log(`Value of sumGrades after the for loop: ${sumGrades}`); //this returns NaN, and I dont know why!!
    }

    let avg = (sumGrades/nameGrade.length);
    console.log(`Value of sumGrades/array.length: ${avg}`);
```